# SFML - Compiler/Linker Error?

Tags: c++, sfml

I finally get back into SFML, set up the library as needed, and get the "_unwind_resume" and "gxx_personality_v0" errors. I have SFML precompiled for TDM and SJLJ (and have tried both setups) yet still get the same errors with both setups. I'm assuming I'll have to compile the source of SFML for my specific version of GCC... again.

What exactly causes these errors? I know it's an issue with the compiler and linker, but what exactly happens when these errors come up? How can I maintain SFML to make sure I don't have to encounter this error once again?